# Trouble with Focus out Event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to reduce the height of the App when the MainWindow gets out of focus, but with the code below nothing like that happens.

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        time_frame_values = [i/30 for i in range(30)]
        self.timeFrame = map(lambda x: x**0.5, time_frame_values)


    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
            self.on_focus_out()
            print("Focus Out!")
        return False

    def on_focus_out(self):
        print("Focus Out!!")
        for i in reversed(self.timeFrame):
            self.move(QPoint(ScreenSizeObject.width()-self.width()-10, ScreenSizeObject.height()-self.original_height-(i*300)))
            self.ui.textDisplay.resize(QSize(self.ui.textDisplay.width(), self.ui.textDisplay.height() + (i * 15)))

            time.sleep(0.01)
```

Here `self.on_focus_out()` will do the transition effect.

EXPECTATION: When I click anywhere out of the mainwindow I want the `self.on_focus_out()` to run.

REALITY: No TRANSITION EFFECT takes place, not even the `print('Focus Out!')` prints a character.

Thanks for your effort!!

Comment: You need to override [changeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent) and monitor window activation/deactivation/state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the desired behavior you are looking for, 
change the `QEvent.FocusOut` to `QEvent.WindowDeactivate` and the problem is Solved!

Rewriting the Correct Code,

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        time_frame_values = [i/30 for i in range(30)]
        self.timeFrame = map(lambda x: x**0.5, time_frame_values)


    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            self.on_focus_out()
            print("Focus Out!")
        return False

    def on_focus_out(self):
        print("Focus Out!!")
        for i in reversed(self.timeFrame):
            self.move(QPoint(ScreenSizeObject.width()-self.width()-10, ScreenSizeObject.height()-self.original_height-(i*300)))
            self.ui.textDisplay.resize(QSize(self.ui.textDisplay.width(), self.ui.textDisplay.height() + (i * 15)))

            time.sleep(0.01)
```